# Why does $\frac{f(x)}{\frac{f(y)}{h}} = \frac{f(x)}{hf(y)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Earlier, I asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251317/why-does-fraca-fracbx-x-times-fracab), but this one's getting me confused, as well. Why does $\frac{a}{\frac{b}{x}} = x \times \frac{a}{b}$, but the following [expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%2Ff%28y%29%2Fh) holds true?

$$
\frac{f(x)}{\frac{f(y)}{h}} = \frac{f(x)}{hf(y)}
$$

Comment: You did not use parentheses, and Alpha interpreted your question as $\dfrac{\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}}{h}$. Note the thicker "fraction line" in Alpha. Generally, if you don't use parentheses, Alpha reads from left to right. If you want Alpha to operate correctly, use $f(x)/(f(y)/h)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha took it as $\frac{\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}}{h}$ instead of $\frac{f(x)}{\frac{f(y)}{h}}$. You need to see which line is longer more carefully. The longer line represents the division performed later.

Comment: It's not just Wolfram Alpha, though. My prof had a similar expression to the one my question.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{f(x)}{\frac{f(y)}{h}}\cdot \frac{h}{h}=\frac{f(x)\cdot h}{\frac{f(y)}{h}\cdot h}=\frac{f(x)h}{f(y)}.$$

What Jasper Loy said too.